# How to ignore action spam in an effect

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am relatively new to ngrx and have a question that I could not find any answer for so far.

I have a component that updates the name property of an entity with a pessimistic approach, meaning that I first want to have a successful response from the Backend before really updating the state.

For that I am using the Action pattern where I have an updateName, updateNameScuccess and updateNameFail Action and an update$ effect that sends the new name to the API and dispatches a success or a fail action.

```
public updateMyThingsItemName$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(
    MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemName
  ),
  exhaustMap((action) =>
    this.myThingsService.patchMyThingsItem(action.myThingsItem.id, action.myThingsItem.changes).pipe(
      map((myThingsItem) => MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemSuccess({ myThingsItem })),
      catchError((error: string) => of(MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemFailure({ error })))
    )
  )
));
```

I am using the `exhaustMap` operator so if a user spams the update button that dispatches the `updateMyThingsItemName` action I do not send multiple identical requests to the backend.

Now I also have another effect that does present a loading indicator for the `updateMyThingsItemName` action and one that dismisses the indicator again if the update was successful or failed:

```
public presentLoadingSpinner$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(
    MyThingsItemActions.updateMyThingsItemName
  ),
  tap(async () => {
    await this.loadingService.presentLoader('loading...');
  })
), {
  dispatch: false
});
```

Because the side effect for displaying the loading spinner listens to every new `updateMyThingsItemName` action, as soon as the user spams the button on the UI that dispatches that action, an additional loading spinner is created.
And because that side effect does not dispatch an action by itself I can not use exhaust map either.

How can I write this effect to ignore action spamming?

Answer (score 0):

I think the common solution is to add a loading state property to the state.
Based on the property you can show/hide spinners.

- Fetch => set state to `loading`
- Success => set state to `success`
- Error => set state to `error`

Then you can write a selector to retrieve the current loading state, which you can use to show/hide spinners.
There are some variations to this, but I think the following one matches your current structure.

```
public presentLoadingSpinner$ = createEffect(() => this.store.select(loadingStateSelector),
  filter(loadingState => loadingState === 'loading'),
  tap(async () => {
    await this.loadingService.presentLoader('loading...');
  })
), {
  dispatch: false
});
```

Comment: I do have a loading property in my state, but the "problem" is that I do only want to show the spinner on some actions. But I guess I could solve it with a "spinner" property. Another solution could be to create a global state for a spinner as a feature itself and dispatch a ShowSpinner action or something like that. But I am not sure weather or not that is good architecture as I am kind of new with ngrx